# code sense style autocomplete for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xcode, eclipse-plugin

I've been playing around with XCode lately and I've really taken to the way code sense does the whole intelligent autocomplete in grey while you type thing.

Are there any plugins that improve on the auto completion of eclipse?
Not that ctrl+space in eclipse is bad or anything, it just seems as though codesense is slightly better (in some ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to integrate XCode codesense within an Eclipse CDT (C/C++) or JDT (Java).
For CDT, there was for a time a project to port XCode to the Eclipse platform ([objectiveclipse](http://code.google.com/p/objectiveclipse/)) due to some [frustrations with XCode](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2009/02/objectiveclipse.html), but [it got shutdown since](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2010/06/objectiveclipse-project-closing-doors.html).

That leaves you with the only option of implementing and "Eclipse auto-completion" extension, a bit like the ones you can find in an [XText plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) (whose sources are available).